# Is it possible to use docker to temporary create a test environment?

Tags: docker, testing, open-policy-agent

I have a node.js service which stores access policies that is sent to [open policy agent](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/) service when application starts. Policies can be testes, but to do so they need to be run in open policy agent environment which is not a part of my service. Is there a way to run these tests when building my node.js service docker image? So the image won't be build unless all the tests pass?

So, the dockerfile could look something like this:

```
FROM openpolicyagent/opa:latest
CMD ["test"]
# somehow check that all tests pass and if not return an error
FROM node:8
# node-related stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting everything into one project you could maybe create a build pipeline where you build your Node app and the Envoy+OPA proxy separately and then have yet another independent project that contains the access rule tests and uses maybe Cypress. Your build pipeline could then install the new version to the DEV enviromment unconditionally but requires the separate test project to pass until it deploys on STAGE and PROD environments.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `RUN` statement for desired steps, for example:

```
FROM <some_base_image>

RUN mkdir /tests
WORKDIR /tests
COPY ./tests .    
RUN npm install && npm run build && npm test

RUN mkdir /src
WORKDIR /src
COPY ./src .    
RUN npm install && npm run build

CMD npm start
```

Note: `RUN` gets executed during building an image while `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` get executed during launching container from built image.